# How to refresh a TemplateSlot in a dynamic FormFunction?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, templates

I am building a [`FormFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormFunction.html) that makes use of a [`TemplateSlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateSlot.html) to define a field. This minimal example demonstrates the issue.

```
FormFunction[
  {
   "state" -> "USState", 
   "county" -> TemplateSlot["state"]["Subdivisions"]
  }, Identity]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

This works as expected with the `"county"` field being created with the `"state"`'s counties once the state is entered and <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is pressed.

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

However, if I change the state and select <kbd>Tab</kbd> again the counties do not refresh to the new state. It just highlights the text of the new state.

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

How can the `TemplateSlot` be refreshed when its dependent field is updated?

I tried wrapping `TemplateSlot` in [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) without success.

```
FormFunction[
  {
   "state" -> "USState", 
   "county" -> Dynamic[TemplateSlot["state"]["Subdivisions"]]
  }, Identity]
```

The UI will be used on the desktop but I prefer a solution that will work when deployed to the cloud.  Also I want to stick with the [Creating Form Interfaces & Apps](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CreatingFormsAndApps.html) guide's form approach instead of the [Custom Interface Construction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CustomInterfaceConstruction.html) approach.

---

Notebook with all issues demonstrated as requested.

```
Import["http://halirutan.github.io/Mathematica-SE-Tools/decode.m"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGPpQ.png"]
```

Comment: See `FormControl`. It’s new in 11 and looks like it’ll handle this case.

Comment: @b3m2a1 That does not quite work. Even is you set `"AutoSubmitting"->True` on the field the value is `"state"` gets over written with the `InputForm` of the entity. This messes up the display and the value.

Comment: @Edmund do you want to deploy it at the end?

Comment: @Kuba Yes, it will be deployed.

Comment: @Edmund I'm 90% sure that all efforts to make desktop's form behave well will be useless in cloud. Worth to mention what is the final goal. p.s. I was playing with 'dynamic' form functions once, but the conclusion was that they are 'dynamic only once' :) which is pretty limited. I'm afraid that custom html/js or a CloudCDF solution is the only flexible answer.

Comment: Do you have a solution now? Has WRI confirmed the limitation?

Comment: @Kuba Unfortunately WRI has confirmed this and a few other points I raised as a limitation of form building and functionality. Forms have only been around for a few versions so I hope my request gets the ball rolling at WRI for some improvements to the framework.

Comment: @Edmund Consider posting the official statement as an answer. It is good to know where the limits are.

Comment: Looking to do the same thing. There's a lot I'd like to do with Forms but it looks like I'm going to have to stick with InputFields for now. Is that what everyone else is doing?